# MySql Query: Total Average for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, oracle

I want to calculate the overall average GPA for all of the students in one of the departments, this is what I came up with but it does it not work

```
COLUMN AVERAGE FORMAT 0.999  
SELECT  AVG(GPA) "AVERAGE"  
FROM    STUDENT  
WHERE   (YEAR < 4) AND 
        (MAJOR LIKE '%ACCT%') AND 
        (MAJOR LIKE '%FINA%') AND 
        (MAJOR LIKE '%MGMT%') AND 
        (MAJOR LIKE '%AISY%') AND 
        (MAJOR LIKE '%MINS%') AND 
        (MAJOR LIKE '%SCMS%');
```

so they should be both undergraduates and be enrolled in one of those majors.

Also as an additional question: is it possible to write such a query using "GROUP BY ### and HAVING ###) ? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the average for all students with Year < 4 in one of the following majors.  I believe your issue was the use of `AND` instead of `OR` for the majors.  It is unlikely there were students in a major whose name matched all of those strings.

```
SELECT AVG(GPA) AS "AVERAGE"  
FROM STUDENT
WHERE (YEAR < 4)
   AND
   (
      (MAJOR LIKE '%ACCT%') OR
      (MAJOR LIKE '%FINA%') OR 
      (MAJOR LIKE '%MGMT%') OR 
      (MAJOR LIKE '%AISY%') OR 
      (MAJOR LIKE '%MINS%') OR 
      (MAJOR LIKE '%SCMS%')
   )
```